# JS Dictionary from nested array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have array like this

```
let tempArr = [
 {
   id:1,
   children:{
     id:2,
     children:{
       id:100
     }
   }
 }
]
```

I need array with 'path' like this

```
arr = [
 {
   100:[1,2]
 }
]
```

please help

Comment: Please include the code you've tried and we can help with any specific questions you have about that.

Comment: is `[1, 2]` the values of `id`?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: If you feel more comfortable with Russian (compared to English), there is a https://ru.stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this

```js
const ids = []
let children = tempArr[0]
while (children) {
  ids.push(children.id)
  children = children.children
}
const res = [{ [ids.at(-1)]: ids.slice(0, -1) }]
console.log(res); // [ { 100: [ 1, 2 ] } ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Map through array and recursively collect id's.

```js
let tempArr = [
 {
   id:1,
   children:{
     id:2,
     children:{
       id:100
     }
   }
 }
];

function getId({ id, children }, prev = []) {
  if (!children) {
    prev.push(id);
    return;
  }
  
  prev.push(id);
  
  getId(children, prev);
  
  return prev;
}

const output = tempArr.map(item => {
  const ids = getId(item);
  const key = ids.pop();
  return { [key]: ids };
});

console.log(output);
```

If you are not into recursive solution and performance is important, then iterative solution will be faster when you have deep nested object.

```
const output = tempArr.map(item => {
  const ids = [];
  
  while (item.children) {
    ids.push(item.id);
    item = item.children;
  }
  
  const key = ids.pop();
  
  return { [key]: ids };
});
```

Comment: Exactly that I want. Thank You!